# Why does my search function only match when I miss off the first character?

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I have written a search function from scratch using jQuery, to meet a specific need. It searches data from the `<span>` of a `<div>` and then hides the `<div>` if it doesn't match the string in a textbox.

The problem I have is it will recognise strings but not the first character. It is also case sensitive, and this is not a feature I want to include.

```
 //Grab ID of current recordContainer
            var currentID = $(this).attr('id');
        // Add hash tag so it can be used as an ID call
            var currentID2 = ("#" + currentID);
        //Grab data from author span in current recordContainer
            var currentAuthor = $(this).children('span.listLeadAuthor').text();
        //If current author matches anything in the search box then keep it visible
            if (currentAuthor.search(searchBox1) > 0)
            {
                    $(currentID2).show();
                    count++;
            }
        //If search box is empty keep it visible
            else if (searchBox1 === "")
            {
                    $(currentID2).show();
            }
```

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZwFpR/1/)

Comment: Please copy-paste the code in the question as well.

Comment: `currentAuthor.search(searchBox1) !== -1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your if statement is ignoring the first character since the first character is at index 0.

```
if (currentAuthor.search(searchBox1) > 0)
```

Should be:

```
if (currentAuthor.search(searchBox1) >= 0)
```

---

If you're after case sensitivity you will need to apply either `toUpperCase()` or `toLowerCase()`.

```
if (currentAuthor.ToUpperCase().search(searchBox1.toUpperCase()) >= 0)
```

Comment: This is great, but it's still case sensitive.

Comment: found the fix

        if (currentAuthor.search(new RegExp(searchBox1, "i")) !== -1)

Answer (score 2):

> The problem I have is it will recognise strings but not the first character.

Your problem is right here:

```
if (currentAuthor.search(searchBox1) > 0)
```

String.search in JS gets you the *position* of the first match. If that’s right a the beginning of your text, then it is `0`.

The return value for *no match found* is not `0`, but `-1`.